# Default way to handle resources in cmake

Tags: resources, cmake

I have a little problem with my current c++ project, which uses cmake to automate the build process. The projects structure is not simple, because it consists out of a couple of subprojects(4 of them), but I hope this does not influence my problem.

Some of my sub-projects have beside their headers and source files a folder called data, which contains many images, configuration files, and some other things. What I want is, that my program can access the files in the data directory, when it gets executed in the build directory(by my IDE), and also, if it is installed somewhere with `make install`.

I already resolved it with copying the data file, when `make install` is executed with the following cmake code:

```
install(FILES ${resources} DESTINATION data)
```

This seems to work, but it is not really nice, because I have to list all my resources(they are MANY), and the execution in the IDE is still not working, because I do not have the resources in my binary tree.

What should I do, to access my resources out of the binary tree? I think copying is not a nice solution, because my resources are multiple megabytes big, and copying on each build sounds stupid.

Comment: I would make the location of the resource directory runtime-discoverable.  Perhaps use some platform-specific tricks to discover the location of the running binary, and build the resource directory name from that.  Or search a series of directories.

Comment: I already thought about something like that. Perhaps an environment variable pointing to the source directory. Does anyone know a way, how to append an environment variable in cmake, to make my IDE execute it with that variable?

Comment: What about just building it into the executable?  If it doesn't exist, (during a real install) no harm done.  Have cmake pass the source location via a compile definition `ADD_DEFINITION`, or via CONFIG_FILE.

Comment: That also sounds like a good idea, but the environment attempt sounds a little bit more "clean". Do you know, how to set an env variable for the build environment?

Comment: Depends on the build environment, which breaks some of the utility of CMAKE.

Comment: My project is able to compile under linux, macosx, windows all 64 and 32 bit and arm. And I need all of these targets.